# Overlapping tables in reportviewer

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a reportviewer control to which I feed a SSRS report.
The report that gets generated is fairly large to fit in single view.
So when we see that report in reportviewer on Firefox 11+ or chrome 15+ the tables rendered are overlapped but it runs perfectly well in IE.

Is there any generic solution for these.
Refer Image:[image]

Comment: Officially, Microsoft only supports IE, Firefox and Safari in SSRS. All other browsers are therefore unsupported, and they will not try to find a workaround. On your problem now : Usually, when you have overlapped tables, you have a warning telling you so in the designer. Is it the case? Try putting a 5px spacing between your tables. Does that help?

Comment: no such error in **BIDS** preview mode nor on browser, I have used <div style="page-break"><hr></div> after each table, tried removing it too, no effect.

Comment: Which ReportViewer are you using? Version 9.0.0.0 or 10.0.0.0?

Comment: Its 9.0 and reports hosted on SQL Server 2005

Comment: In that case @DominicGoulet's comment is probably spot on: browser support in 9.0.0.0 is terrible. I've answered your question as it stands now. If you really must fix this *particular* issue you'll have to provide more details (e.g. RDL code) with which we can reproduce the issue: feel free to edit the question and add the details, or start a new question with the code / steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some bad news for you, I'm afraid. Browser support outside IE in version 9.0.0.0 (the 2008 version) is... terrible. As Microsoft states on the [corresponding MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

> Internet Explorer is recommended if you want to use all of the available functionality. Although you can use other browsers to view a report, Internet Explorer is the only browser that is guaranteed to support the complete set of features used for working with reports.

With version 10.0.0.0 things improved. In our experience, they improved *a lot*. [This MS blog post from 2009](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/06/18/where-s-the-new-report-viewer.aspx) also mentions this:

> Significantly improved browser compatibility.  We’ve put a huge amount of effort into improving our support across browsers.  We’ve seen plenty of reports of extra scrollbars or other problematic renderings in Firefox, Safari, and standards mode in general.  The initial feedback on these changes has been very positive.

The [corresponding MSDN page on ReportViewer 10.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is also quite a bit less "pushy" about users having to resort to IE. There's still a few things that are IE-specific (printing and zooming, for example).

We've experienced the same issues, such as overlapping tables... and then some. Trying to override the styles that were causing this turned out hard, if not impossible. However, just about all of those issues with layouting were gone after we upgraded to 10.0.0.0.

So, I started my answer with "I have some bad news", so here it is: **AFAIK you can't reasonably solve these issues without upgrading** to the newer Report Viewer.