# Export to excel from SSRS 2005 screws up drilldown levels

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I have three levels of grouping in SSRS report as follows

```
+ Heading 1
- Heading 2
  + Heading 2 Group 1
  - Heading 2 Group 2
    + Heading 2 Group 2  Sub group 1
    - Heading 2 Group 2  Sub group 2
      Detail 1
      Detail 2
```

It appears fine in IE reports, but when I export to excel, the first two levels appear with the groups collapsed. On expanding the second group, all the rows (the sub groups and the details) shows up without any grouping button.

Can any one please help me on how to get the third level of grouping also on the excel.

Comment: I have not ran across this one in particular, but there are MANY limitations in SSRS 2005 that have been resolved in later versions. I know that the formatting in SSRS 2008 is almost exactly like the UI report.

Comment: Second @DustinLaine. Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11264122/419956) to a different, yet similar question. Are you at all able to upgrade to SSRS 2008?

Comment: I will ask the Infra team if they can upgrade mine to SSRS 2008. But I am not too sure if that will be easy. I will try though.